# How can I show the progress of a JavaScript on the webpage?

Tags: javascript, progress-bar

My javascript code takes a long time to run and I want to show the user the percentage of progress. All references to progress bars I've encountered increment based on fixed time intervals using setInterval. How do I show progress based on incremental variables in my code?

Comment: That depends on what your code actually does. Is it possible to calculate a percentage of how far your code is along its calculations?

Comment: Yes. it consists of a series of loops. I just need to show how close the increment variables are to the end of the loops.